# how to create conditional arguments in a function?

Tags: powershell

I have the following function that hides a password middle chars and leaves 1st and last char visible

```
function Hide-ConnectionStringPassword {
    param(
       [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
       [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]$ConnectionString
    )
    [string]$FistChar = $ConnectionString.Password[0]
    [string]$LastChar = $ConnectionString.Password[($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 1)]
    [string]$Stars = '*' * ($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 2)
    $ConnectionString.Password = $FistChar + $Stars + $LastChar 
    return $ConnectionString.ConnectionString
}
```

Usage:

```
Hide-ConnectionStringPassword 'Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553;'
```

output:

> Data Source=datasource.com;User
>   ID=UID1;Password=p************3;Connect Timeout=120

I have other connection strings that are JSON formatted, so the casting to sqlbuilder will not work on this type of input

> {"Authentication
>   Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"Yu#gh456!ts","EncryptConnection":true}

One thing i could do is something like this:

```
$Json = '{"Authentication Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"Yu#gh456!ts","EncryptConnection":true}'
$Sql = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Sql.Password
```

with

```
$Sql.gettype().name
```

i get

> PSCustomObject

i would like to apply that in the function such that it checks string input is type pscustomobject so that it doesnt cast it as sqlbuilder

***pseudocode***:

```
function Hide-ConnectionStringPassword {
    if ($input.gettype().name -ne 'PSCustomObject')
    {
    param(
       [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
       [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]$ConnectionString
    )}
    else
    {
    param(
       [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
       $ConnectionString
    )}
    [string]$FistChar = $ConnectionString.Password[0]
    [string]$LastChar = $ConnectionString.Password[($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 1)]
    [string]$Stars = '*' * ($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 2)
    $ConnectionString.Password = $FistChar + $Stars + $LastChar 
    return $ConnectionString.ConnectionString
}
```

Comment: Why not just remove the hard typing in the parameter and do the type conversion in the `Begin {}` area of your function? You can do the `if-else` stuff there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove the hard typing in the parameter. Then move the `if-else` logic to the script `Process {}` or `Begin {}` script blocks.

```
function Hide-ConnectionStringPassword {

    param(
       [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
       $ConnectionString
    )

    if ($ConnectionString.GetType().Name -ne "PSCustomObject") {
    $ConnectionString = $ConnectionString -as [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]
    }

    [string]$FistChar = $ConnectionString.Password[0]
    [string]$LastChar = $ConnectionString.Password[($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 1)]
    [string]$Stars = '*' * ($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 2)
    $ConnectionString.Password = $FistChar + $Stars + $LastChar 
    return $ConnectionString.ConnectionString
}
```

Comment: not sure how i didnt think of this. sometimes, brain freeze is a delimma